# c++ running error

Tags: c++

I am getting this error while running my-program (which compiles fine with g++):

```
my-program: malloc.c:2451: sYSMALLOc: Assertion `(old_top == (((mbinptr) (((char *) &((av)->bins[((1) - 1) * 2])) - __builtin_offsetof (struct malloc_chunk, fd)))) && old_size == 0) || ((unsigned long) (old_size) >= (unsigned long)((((__builtin_offsetof (struct malloc_chunk, fd_nextsize))+((2 * (sizeof(size_t))) - 1)) & ~((2 * (sizeof(size_t))) - 1))) && ((old_top)->size & 0x1) && ((unsigned long)old_end & pagemask) == 0)' failed.
```

I usually understand the error but this time I have no idea what's wrong.

Comment: Most probably you have an index out of the boundaries of one of your arrays, causing a mess on the heap.

Comment: It looks like you might have heap corruption

Comment: This is when assertions could use a `condition && "text explaining error"`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There was a failure inside `malloc`, which means that you've probably corrupted the heap.  Probably by writing past the end of some dynamically-allocated memory somewhere.

Comment: Okay, how can I find where it is that this is happening ?

Comment: @evaG, this is a hard to spot error in general, but try running your program with `valgrind`, you would most probably get errors for accessing out of array boundaries.

Comment: @evaG: If you're running on Linux (or similar), then you can (and should) use [Valgrind](http://valgrind.org).  It's designed to track exactly this kind of problem.

Comment: Okay, I am indeed using linux, how can I use valgrind with waf (code.google.com/p/waf/) ? I normally run it with ./waf --run my-program. So should I just use 'valgrind ./waf --run my-program' ? Because I did, and my program run, but valgrind didn't display anything regarding any memory errors. The same error was displayed though.

Comment: It's ok I'm just talking about how to run valgrind. I  basically tried just using 'valgrind my-program', but nothing special was displayed regarding possible memory errors.

Comment: @evaG: Hmm.  In that case, there's probably something else that's the problem.  I don't really know what that could be, though.

Comment: You should run `valgrind --leak-check=full ./waf --run my-program`